# NSMutableArray to Array of String Conversion Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to populate data in a table view. How can I convert [NSMutableArray?] to [(String)] in Swift iOS

> println(self.subcategory[index]!) i.e., an [NSMutableArray?], where
>   index is Int shows:

```
(
    Operations,
    Marketing,
    "Public Relations",
    "Human Resources",
    Advertising,
    Finance,
    Hotels,
    Restaurants,
    Other
)
```

Comment: show the data in [nsmutablearray?]

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati Updated.

Comment: the answer is:
let swiftArray = self.subcategory[index] as! AnyObject as! [String]

Comment: the above result you printed is only one call of `println(self.subcategory[index]!)` or `println(self.subcategory)`

Comment: i mean there is nested array in your nsmutablearray?

Comment: thanks. I figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this.

```
 let myArray : NSMutableArray = ["Operations"]
    myArray.addObject("Marketing")
    myArray.addObject("Public Relations")
    myArray.addObject("Human Resources")

    myArray.addObject("Advertising")
    myArray.addObject("Finance")
    myArray.addObject("Hotels")
    myArray.addObject("Restaurants")
    myArray.addObject("Other")

    NSLog("\(myArray)")

    var string = myArray.componentsJoinedByString(",")
    NSLog("\(string)")
```

Comment: I'm parsing JSON Data. This doesn't add up.

Comment: can you your data type by "iskindofclass"? or give some lines of code or give you url then i can check what type of data you got

Comment: thank you all.!
the answer is: let swiftArray = self.subcategory[index] as! AnyObject as! [String]